# Error starting a server with express/node.js. Following The Coding Train YouTube tutorial

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-side

There were other somewhat similar questions on this site, but none that could help me specifically.

Here is the link to the video I am following [2.1 Server-side with Node.js - Working with Data and APIs in JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxbQP1LMZsw)

At 15:17 in the video, I get the errors

**1.** GET http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)

**2.** Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

credit: 'The Coding Train'

javascript below

```
/// index.js ///
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at 3000'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

html below, in a folder called **public**

```
/// tutorial_2_1.html ///
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Data Selfie App</h1>
  <p>Hello?</p>
</body>

</html>
```

the node_modules folder is also in my directory.

This is my first question, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The file may need to be named `index.html`, rather than `tutorial_2_1.html`.  Otherwise try going to `localhost:3000/tutorial_2_1.html`

Comment: Changing the name to index.html worked, but I don't understand why the name of the html file would matter, any idea? And thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Because it is typical server standards that if a filename is not given, that `index.html` is served up by default.

Comment: Appreciate the info.